# ERR Missing script critical

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to generate critical css path using node module by addy osmania (https://github.com/addyosmani/critical)

i have below code in package json

```
"scripts": {
"criticalcss": "node criticalcss.mjs",
}
```

when i do npm run critical i get bellow error...

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "critical"
```

What am i doing wrong? My node installation is in c:user/admin and my production files are in xampp htdocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used `node script.mjs` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your script is named `criticalcss` and you are running the command `npm run critical`.

Try

```
npm run criticalcss
```